# What does this single line of webpack html loader syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, config, loader

To solve a problem I was having with my `webpack.config.js` file I copied a line from [a webpack blog](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/setting-up-webpack-for-react-and-hot-module-replacement). The line is starred in the code below. However I can't seem to easily figure out what the line is doing and googling didn't lead me to a simple explanation. So, what is the purpose/syntax of the indicated line? A short explanation would probably suffice, but a link to some (official) documentation would also be helpful.

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        javascript: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js'],
        html: './index.html'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtools: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]' // <---- **********
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webpack file loader lets you specify a custom filename template for imported files using the `name=` query parameter:

https://github.com/webpack/file-loader#filename-templates

Comment: Your link takes me to the exact information I was looking for, e.g. explaining `name` and `ext`, and [a further link from there](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html) takes me to more general information about using loaders, e.g. explaining `?` and `!`. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Webpack 1 supports configuring a loader entirely through a query-string like DSL.  Written in the alternative syntax for configuration makes it clear(er) what is going on:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  loader: 'file', // Use the file loader
  query: {  // Configuring it with the following options
    name: '[name].[ext]'
    // Set the name of the HTML files that are output to be
    // the local name of the file, followed by a literal dot character
    // followed by the file's extension.
  }
}
```

Comment: I chose the answer from @7zark7 because of the link(s). However, you've provided some very useful information about alternative syntax that is not (or at least not obviously) described in that answer, its direct link or the second link I mentioned. Thanks.